# detecting difference between two different taken images for the same view

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am taking  pictures for a paper with big dots and trying to detect the added dots in the next pic. 
For example in the shown two pics I should be able to identify the 16 added dots.
[image: Image with paper containing two dots]

[image: image with paper containing 18 dots]

I tried to use compare_ssim from scikit to detect them but It didn't get any dots because the two images aren't perfectly aligned.
After that I tried to align the images following this [tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/) 
before compare_ssim but it detected all the dots as changes in the two images besides that it detected other changes in the background as shown in the image below.[image: code result]

The code used and the test images are in this [folder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Yy_GNSwrtEWhQj6SmJ0jt_0qAckgPg1m)

Comment: The other 'changes' in the background are found, because the lighting changes constantly. You would need to set up some kind of margin within which the small lighting fluctuations is ignored.

Comment: how can I apply that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by :

1. Detecting the paper in the image paper before and after using ORB detector.
2. After that applying Image alignment as in the tutorial to the cropped images.
3. comparing the cropped Images using compare_ssim.
4. detecting the new added holes by using BLOB detector on the result of step no. 3

Comment: Hey, Can you share the code ! if possible

Answer (score 1):

One of the main problems seems to be the transformation is not correctly applied.
It can be clearly seen in the images you shared, that both the papers are not correctly aligned.

I suggest you do the alignment by yourself. It should not be that hard. But if you wish to go ahead with the current approach, it is fine as well.

Next instead of directly using compare_ssim try the following.

1. Detect the dots in the transformed initial image.
2. Extract their centroids.
3. In the Second image, detect all the dots.
4. Remove the dots from the second image that have the centroids of transformed initial image in them.

This should give better results.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but for the part concerning detecting the dots won't work for me, the question is just a simple example for the real part in my application. I am working on detecting bullet holes for shooters in the training but the holes are very hard hard to detect so I am trying to figure the difference between the two images to get the result as shown in the images here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VzA5ff2eBQIRJdWsBkTUTp0CIepyoD_5 , you will find there is an image with no bullets at all and the other one with two holes that are very hard to detect

Comment: Oh, I see. It sure is difficult to detect holes in the image, attest visually. I would suggest that you detect the paper in the image and use some other technique to calculate the homogenious transform matrix.

Comment: That's what I am currently trying to do, Thanks